# Using handlebars, if string is empty, then add display none class to HTML element

Tags: html, if-statement, handlebars.js

I have a CTA that is currently always rendered, however, I want to ensure that the CTA is only rendered if a link has been provided (in JSON object) with Handlebars.

So if `"ctaText"` is an empty string, add the `d-none` class, otherwise, show as normal.

I've tried using `unless` but to no avail, can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML);

const data = {
  "ctaText": "",
  "otherProps": true,
]
}

const output = template(data);

document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  {{#unless viewAllLink}}
  <a class="cta d-none" href="#">
    <span class="cta-text">View all</span>
    <span class="cta-icon"></span>
  </a>
  {{else}}
  <a class="cta" href="{{viewAllLink}}">
    <span class="cta-text">View all</span>
    <span class="cta-icon"></span>
  </a>
  {{/unless}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post is confusing because in your description you state that you want your rendering to be conditional on the truthiness of `ctaText`, but in your template it is conditional upon `viewAllLink` - and you have not `viewAllLink` in the data you are passing to your template.

You certainly *can* use `unless` as your conditional helper, but, personally, I find this much more difficult to understand than would be the case for a simple `if` - as in: "*if* we have `ctaText`, render the link with it".

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Template').innerHTML);

const data = {
  "ctaText": "My Text"
};

const output = template(data);

document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="Template" type="text/template">
  <div class="btn-container">
    {{#if ctaText}}
      <a class="cta" href="{{viewAllLink}}">
        <span class="cta-text">{{ctaText}}</span>
        <span class="cta-icon"></span>
      </a>
    {{else}}
      <a class="cta d-none" href="#">
        <span class="cta-text">View all</span>
        <span class="cta-icon"></span>
      </a>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</script>
<div id="Output"></div>
```